# Videoplayer for many 15sec. snippets with easy jumping between snippets (behavior analysis)

Tags: data-analysis, r, video-player

I am looking for a video player or way to program in R the following functions:

- A 10min. long video (or 40 individual 15sec. Videos) is played in 15sec. snippets. I.e. 0-14sec. 15-29sec. and so on.
- Within each 15sec. snippet behavior is observed and categorized (1,2,3, etc.) -> preferably with a keypress, saving into csv or anything.
- The player should stop playback at the end of each snippet. And rewind to the beginning of the snippet at a button press. switching between snippets would be nice.
- File name of the snippet should be visible somewhere, doesn't matter where, window border is fine as well.

I have looked at R's video capabilities and only found recommendations to use something different. Maybe someone can point me in the right direction. I think from there I can manage grabbing keys and saving into csv.

Or maybe there is already software out there to exactly this.